# Accessing parent folder packages from inside a package

Tags: java, package

If i have a class inside a package say `mypackage.myclass` and want to access a package's class that is in the same folder as the package's root (not inside the package) say `anothepackage.anotherclass` how can I actually do so?

Example presented in code:

```
// directories are preceded by a DIR, files are preceded by a CLASS
// any level deeper is preceded by a [Tab]
DIR mypackage
    CLASS myclass
    DIR myinnerpackage
        CLASS myinnerclass
DIR anotherpackage
    CLASS anotheclass
CLASS yetanotherclass
DIR org
    DIR apache
        DIR commons
            DIR exec
                CLASS DefaultExecutor
```

Inside the file myclass:

```
package mypackage;

public class myclass{
    // simplest example  code I can come up with
    org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor exec = new org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor();
}
```

Why does this piece of code not work for me?

Generally how can `myclass` access `anotherclass` or `yetanotherclass` and how can `myinnerclass` access them as well? Try to refrain for imports as I want to use certain members of each class only (some variables have same names and will get things messed)! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about `import` statement?

Comment: No, I ask how to access a class that is in a parent directory of another class.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? If you want to use a class in a different package, you use the `import` statement (but that's basic stuff that maybe you already know (: ). If you want to get file content (or related), then remember that packages are just folders and Class.java are files. If the last was your case, then Eng.Fouad has achieved the answer.

Comment: Basically I want to use a variable from `anotherclass` in a statement of `myclass` without the full import for a couple of reasons. Like if I want to use `int variableA` from `anotherclass` in a statement inside `myclass` will I do it like `int a = ../anotherpackage/anotherclass.variableA +10`?

Comment: That's not how Java works. Assuming this `anotherclass.variableA` is a `static int` variable and you don't want to use `import` statement, then you need to call the fullname class: `int a = mypackage.myinnerpackage.myinnerclass.variableA + 10;` but this is clumsy.

Comment: Yeah I am totally sure it is clumsy, but still it is kind of my best bet, still this does not work and I am clueless... :/

Comment: In cases like this, you should post your functional requirement and ask for guidance, maybe showing some code (not all the code) in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) form would help people to give better help for your problem.

Comment: It is about 300 lines and totally irrelevant but will try to get around a small example if this is the case... ;)

Comment: Here, have a quick small example with the least possible code to help you get what is happening. By the way this beauty should work absolutely perfect based on what you guys suggest (and I bet if I was less clumsy it would), but as of now it does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java right?

inside myClass

```
import anotherPackage.anotherClass;
```

and then inside your myClass you can just use

```
  anotherClass ac=new anotherClass();
```

then using object "ac" you can access any of anotherClass properties.

you might want to read about packages and imports

Edit 
without using imports 
i you can use concept of fully qualified name try like

```
anotherPackage.anotherClass ac=new anotherPackage.anotherClass()
```

then use ac toacees anotherClass properties

by the way you mentioned, different classes have some same variables and imports can mess up stuff. Java works around objects, same names aint really gonna messup. even if some variables are static you will be using classnames.staticVar to access. so not much of messing up. :-)

UPDATE : 
the discussion below was moved to chat as it was getting comprehensive 
some usefull snippets from chat

Askee was facing classpath issues

CLASSPATH , as the name suggests it is the path to class.
when we compile a java file, the compiler will look for the resources that the class needs in current directory and on the  classpath. 
everything cann not be in same directory (actually it can be, :-) ) , so we use

```
set CLASSPATH
```

to set classpath and where else to look for classes

in the question the ckass myClass was not getting compilec as

```
org.apache.common.exec.DefaultExecutor was not in classpath
```

suggested to set parent directory on classpath to have it work

```
javac -classpath %cd%\.. myclass.java
```

Comment: Yeah I said I want to refrain from imports and use directly certain variables from anotherclass!

Comment: I guess the "Java" tag means this is a Java question.

Comment: in that case you can use concept of fully qualified name try like "anotherPackage.anotherClass ac=new anotherPackage.anotherClass()“ then use ac to acees anotherClass properties

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yap sorry for not saying that in the question :P
@MukulGoel yeah right if I try to acess a certain static variable of `anotherpackage` without instantiating an object inside my class I get an error, problem is `anotherclass` is an extension of a JFrame... :/

Comment: By the way it does not work eve with instantiating an object as I try it right now... :/

Comment: About the last part, this is something I didn't think of! :P

Do you have any clue why on earth the last piece of code you provided does not work for me? Any typical silly things a programmer may do to break it? :S

Comment: @Spiritios static variable of package ? how did u made a static variable of a package ? :o

Comment: I just realized I am trying to access a raw class that is not a package! I mean it has no package statement in its head... Oh god... :/ But still the apache exec package that is in the same folder as the raw class wont allow me to access it and instantiate an object inside my class... :O

Comment: @Spiritios , chill.. your problem is gonna get resolved. if not by me than there are numerous "bonds" out here on SO. first can you please update your question with recent developments ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17653/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-spiritios)

Answer (score 2):

Use relative path:

```
String dir = "../anotherpackage/anotheclass";
              ^
              |
              -- (go one level up)
```

Comment: So is it exactly like it is in HTML? (Silly me didn't think of it :bashes head on desk:)

Comment: Can you tell me how to do so inside a statement? Like if I want to use `int variableA` from `anotherclass` in a statement inside `myclass` will I do it like `int a = ../anotherpackage/anotherclass.variableA +10`?